# Shortcut key to jump to start of entire string in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

What keyboard shortcut lets you go to the start of a string? I need this for emails. When i use CTRL + back arrow it jumps to the dot and @ sign, i have a block of strings with emails at the end, i want to select only the email by going to the end of the string but as some people have *firstname.lastname@something.com* and *flastname@something.com* the cursors dont line up when i use CTRL + back arrow.

I cant find any specific shortcuts which would help in this situation.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are no built-in commands that will do what you want.  You will need an extension.  I wrote such an extension: [Jump and select](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.jump-and-select).

With this setting (in your `settings.json`):

`"jump-and-select.putCursorBackward": "afterCharacter"   // default is beforeCharacter`

and the default keybinding for jumping backward and selecting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> it is easy to select everything from your cursor to some preceding character.  Just trigger that keybinding and type the character to select backward to, in your case a <kbd>Space</kbd>.  As you can see in the demo, it works with multiple or single cursors.

[image: jump backward and select demo]

Comment: Thanks Mark, yes that's exactly what i'm after. I installed Jump and select and set "jump-and-select.putCursorBackward": "afterCharacter" but when I hit shift+alt+b i get the error "Running the contributed command: 'jump-and-select.jumpBackwardSelect' failed." I see there's an error help but I couldnt work out how to resolve it. Shift+alt+b is the default binding but i'm not sure how to set the character to select back to (i.e space).

Comment: Hmmm, I don't have any errors here.  Did you do a reload after installing the extension? 
 After Shift-alt+b whatever next character you type is where it goes.  You do  not have to set anything - it just intercepts the next single character.

Comment: @Garyb1976 is the extension working for you (after a reload)?  I would like to know if you are still getting the error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by)

You can use the:

- `forward` - `backward`
- `surround`

Add this to your settings:

```
"selectby.regexes": {
  "email": {
    "surround": "[-.a-zA-Z0-9]+@[-.a-zA-Z0-9]+"
  }
}
```

You can call the select with a command or define a keybinding, see the doc page